# I want to migrate an excel & word document report into a modern web app, but not sure where to start, can you help or point me in the right direction?

Tags: excel, html, web-applications

I have an excel audit form which has a lot of yes/no questions. These questions have three fields, compliant, impact, probability & category.

The compliant field is the yes / no and the impact & probability are set numbers from 1-5. Each item then gets a risk score assigned e.g. if impact is 1 and probability is 2 the risk score = 3

At the end it generates a risk score for each of the categories & a nice graph which shows the risk distribution between the categories.

Once the Excel form has been filled out I use the data to pre-fill out a word template report.

A lot of the data in the word document is standard for each report. However there are tables that get manually populated by copying the data from the excel file accross.

I was thinking of a web app where the Yes / No questions are asked and the answers are stored in a database. Once completed the report can be generated from that data and will save a lot of time having to manully create that word report.

I am not really sure where to start, I am not a programmer, I do have an IT degree and happy to spend time learning. The main requirements are for it to be easy to add & remove new questions & to be able to easily generate a nice client facing report.

Can you provide me with some guidance on what the best framework to use would be and if there are any good tutorials that I could follow?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I am new to this website, can you provide feedback on what I should do differently so I don't get down voted?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out what you can do using a combination of a form builder (Google Forms, Wufoo, Jotform), Zapier and DocMerge. This would allow you to string together an application that suits your needs without doing any programming.

Here are some examples of what's possible with Zapier (no affiliation): https://zapier.com/zapbook/google-docs/wufoo/

Answer (score 0):

There are many websites offering what you are asking for. eg surveymonkey